# trying to connect my VS code to the github but in first initialising I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, github

The error is:

```sh
git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S
error: cannot spawn C:\Users\Ali Nekoh\OneDrive\Desktop\website demo: Permission denied
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

How can I get past this?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend not doing a Git repository in a shared/online-backed up folder like Microsoft OneDrive: a concurrent Microsoft process could keep a handle on your various source files and Git data, preventing Windows to access those same data and write in them.

That is why you see a "Permission denied".

One alternative [shown here](https://gist.github.com/gpsarkar/2b82fb69a0e58c3c76badf58ff800e59%23) would be to setup a bare repository on OneDrive (credit: [Ganapati Sarkar](https://github.com/gpsarkar)):

```sh
cd ~/OneDrive
mkdir git
cd git 
mkdir myproject
cd myproject
git init
git config --bool core.bare true
 

# Now go to your workspace, generally this will be any folder in your PC, outside of OneDrive
# Never create your workspace in onedrive or it will save all the files from node_modules.
#
# Lets say worspace is in D:\workspace
#
# Open GitBash
 
cd D:/workspace
git clone ~/OneDrive/git/myproject
cd myproject
touch testfile.txt
git add.
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```